# Nobody would believe what an effort it is **to do what little I am able**,--to dress and entertain, and order things

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Nobody would believe what an effort it is **to do what little I am able**,--to dress and entertain, and order things.
>
> *(a part of "Yellow Wallpaper" by Charlotte Perkins Gilman)*

I don't understand this part quiet clearly.

My understaning is

1. It makes me tired since I am not able to do little while I can or want to do a lot of things (because her husband wants her to rest completely.)
2. Or it makes me tired since I am not in good shape, so even a little bit of work makes me tired.

Which one would be right?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is OT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a famous short story about a woman suffering from a "nervous" condition, which today we would probably call depression.  Her husband forces her to maintain a regimen of inactivity that slowly makes her condition worse.  In the lines you quote, she talks about those things that she's still able to do -- dress, entertain, and order things from shops.  She says that she realizes that this isn't very much, in fact "little," but it still requires an incommensurately large effort.  She says that no one would believe how large an effort it takes her to accomplish so little.

It is beyond the scope of ELU to help you decide the literary interpretation of who is responsible for her condition (the husband, the woman herself, or no one person); whether her condition is physical or mental; and whether her burdens are personal, marital, or societal (or a combination).